# Upgrade Reportviewer version 11 to 14(2016) fails

Tags: c#, .net, report-viewer2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xth3.jpg)I want to upgrade existing old Reportviewer to new Reportviewer 2016.
I am using .net framework 4.6 and its perfectly working  in old version.

Now, when I upgrade to version 14, it will give runtime error(No exception).

Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: elementID

I have made all necessary changes but still I am getting this error.
I have referred below URLs.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/07b569ac-af15-4092-bd42-6aa826b39463/issue-with-report-viewer-control-v14?forum=sqlreportingservices

Error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: elementID

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: elementID

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


    [ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
    Parameter name: elementID]
       System.Web.UI.ScriptComponentDescriptor..ctor(String type, String elementID) +127
       Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewerClientScript.SetViewerInfo(ReportViewer viewer, String reportAreaId, String promptAreaRowId, String docMapAreaId, String fixedTableId, String topLevelUpdatePanelId, String docMapUpdatePanelId, String promptSplitterId, String docMapSplitterId, String docMapHeaderOverflowId, String directionCacheId, String browserModeCacheId, ClientPrintInfo clientPrintInfo) +163
       Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +4335
       System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +162
       System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
       System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6925

    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2103.2
```

Comment: Can you provide stack trace & error details? The stack trace usually useful to find where & what exception was thrown.

Answer (score 5):

Finally found a solution.  Removed ClientIDMode="Static" from the ReportViewer control.